# Why does Aptana/Eclipse have to "build" PHP projects?

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

When I create a new project in Aptana/Eclipse I have to specify that my project should not "build automatically" to avoid this apparently unneeded behavior. **If this was a compiled language I would understand, but since it's PHP why does Aptana need to build, and what is it doing that it takes so long?**

This is especially annoying when I do something like launch a PHP file on the test server and am treated to a never ending status bar as the IDE runs through every file in my jQuery UI and CKEditor libraries, where files are quite numerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build means more than just "compile." For example, it might be validating XML, HTML, JavaScript, etc. files; it can mean copying files to a build output location (it does that for Java projects, but I don't do PHP so I'm not sure if that's part of the PHP build).

To find out a little bit more about what it's doing, open the Project's Properties and check out the Builders section; also see if there's a Validation or XML or other sections there that might allow you to configure what happens during a build. Bottom line, a build shouldn't take more than a few seconds unless something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tasks is to introspect every file, function, class, constant, etc to build the auto-complete list.

If you need to make quick 1-off edits, don't use a heavy IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude items from the build via Right-click > Build > Exclude from build. But yes, the step is necessary if you want proper content assist.